# Free y axis in only some subplots with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, facet-wrap, yaxis

I am trying to plot three different subplots within the same graphic using `facet_wrap`. I know the `y` axis can be settled "free" or "fixed" with the argument `scales` of `facet_wrap()`. However, due to the characteristics of my data, I would like to keep the `y` axis fixed for the first two plots but re-scaled for the third one. I could do three individual plots and arrange them together, but as I am using this code inside a Shiny app this is not the most convenient. Below you will find a minimal example of my data and my code so far.

```
    ##Data example:
    Color Time  Metric
1   Green    0  200.00
2   Green    2  300.00
3   Green    4  600.00
4   Green    6  800.00
5   Green    8 1400.00
6   Green   10 2600.00
7     Red    0  150.00
8     Red    2  260.00
9     Red    4  400.00
10    Red    6  450.00
11    Red    8  600.00
12    Red   10  650.00
13 Yellow    0    0.10
14 Yellow    2    0.20
15 Yellow    4    0.30
16 Yellow    6    0.60
17 Yellow    8    0.55
18 Yellow   10    0.70
    
#With free scales
ggplot(Example) + geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = Metric)) + facet_wrap(facets = "Color", scales = "free")

#With fixed scales:
ggplot(Example) + geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = Metric)) + facet_wrap(facets = "Color", scales = "fixed")
```

As you see, neither alternative is really useful: if I set the scales as `free` I lose the comparison between `Green` and `Red`, which are approximately within the same ranges. However, if I set them as `fix` then it is impossible to see what is going on with `Yellow`. The ideal would be to have `Green` and `Red` on the same scale, and `yellow` in its own scale. Can this be done with `facet_wrap()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this like an option for you, but it uses a variant of `facet_grid()` found in package `facetscales` which allows you to define specific scales. Here the code:

```
#Install
#devtools::install_github("zeehio/facetscales")
library(tidyverse)
library(facetscales)
#Define scales
scales_y <- list(
  `Green` = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2700)),
  `Red` = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 2700)),
  `Yellow` = scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.7))
)
#Code
ggplot(Example) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Time, y = Metric)) +
  facet_grid_sc(Color~.,
                scales = list(y = scales_y))
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
Example <- structure(list(Color = c("Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", 
"Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Yellow", 
"Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow", "Yellow"), Time = c(0L, 
2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 
8L, 10L), Metric = c(200, 300, 600, 800, 1400, 2600, 150, 260, 
400, 450, 600, 650, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.55, 0.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18"))
```